# Unable to install Ubuntu 12.04.1 on Virtualbox on Windows 7 Host

Tags: virtualbox, system-installation

I would like to install Ubuntu 12.04.1 in a virtual box on windows 7 host however I get a black screen after selecting to install Ubuntu i.e. right after choosing English language

I have tried the 32bit and 64bit version desktop version, have also read thru some guides e.g. http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/virtualbox

but I could not find any solution to fix this problem.

BTW I have Ubuntu installed using Virtual PC (not running at the same time), also I have mac OS (mountain lion) installed using Virtual Box so I do not think it is a problem with the virtual box or windows 7 host.

My VM configuration is with 1 core and 1 GB of ram using 20GB VDI; rest is default config.

My hardware is
Core i7 3770k / Asus P8Z77-V Deluxe / GSkill 32GB which I believe should be more than sufficient to run another VM.

I have moved my user profile from SSD to HDD via junction however IMHO it should not matter.

Has anyone else come across this problem and found a solution?

Any help/thoughts on how to solve this would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Hey been there before but not sure how your screen looks. Atleast bu sure to point to the right media source else you incur FATAL : no bootable medium found! System Halted

Comment: Please provide some more information like VirtualBox version, video card settings for the VM in VirtualBox. It might be that either your VirtualBox version installed is out of date for this recent Ubuntu release or that your settings are incompatible. And did you try to install Ubuntu using the 'alternate' installer which is text-only?

Comment: You might want to try the [Alternate Install](http://releases.ubuntu.mirrors.uk2.net/precise/ubuntu-12.04.1-alternate-i386.iso) method.

Comment: @InnocentofUganda : I have the Ubuntu ISO as boot-able medium and it does boot as I am getting prompts for selecting language.

Comment: @gertvdijk:  Virtual box version is 4.1.22 r80657 which is the latest version available. Video card memory is 128MB.  I shall try the alternate installer later tonight and will post results.  thank you for your reply.

Comment: @arcube Video card memory is not the most important setting here. Try disabling acceleration for the installation and enable them later, after installing VirtualBox' guest tools in the guest OS.

Comment: @gertvdijk     I am assuming that by disabling acceleration you meant to remove the check boxes under System->Acceleration tab but I unable to do so as I get a message on virtualbox settings window tht "On the General page, you have selected a 64-bit guest OS type for this VM. As such guests require hardware virtualization (VT-x/AMD-V), this feature will be enabled automatically.

Comment: @Mitch   I have tried the alternate install however it does not boot as well.

Comment: I removed the "quiet" flag from boot options and now I can see some text however the boot process gets hung, the last line is   Freeing initrd memory: 14596k freed.  I can also post the pictures of my settings if someone can tell me how to post it here!

Comment: Guys, this question is unreadable, please put the information in the question, not buried in the comments!